# How to combine multiple stores as Root Store in Mobx and get access of in each other's fields and functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

I don't know how to combine two stores in one RootStore (using Typescript).
For example, I have **liveImageStore.ts** (with methods which request image, also holds array of last 10 image's urls) and **notificationStore.ts** (there are some logic to set/clear notification for further using throughout in whole application. And request in liveImageStore.ts provide some errors (ex., in case of http connection troubles). I would like to call function from **notificationStore.ts** (setNotification which push in store new notification) in request method from first store. But how to forward and type it all?
Notifier component show message use notificationStore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I'm using the root store pattern:

```
class RootStore {
  childStoreOne: ChildStoreOne
  childStoreTwo: ChildStoreTwo

  constructor() {
    this.childStoreOne = new ChildStoreOne(this)
    this.childStoreTwo = new ChildStoreTwo(this)
  }
}

class ChildStoreOne {
  root: RootStore
  constructor(root: RootStore) {
    this.root = root
  }
  methodOne() {}
}

class ChildStoreTwo {
  root: RootStore
  constructor(root: RootStore) {
    this.root = root
  }

  getSomethingFromStoreOne() {
    this.root.childStoreOne.methodOne()
  }
}
```

And this is the React part:

```
// holds a reference to the store (singleton)
let store: RootStore

// create the context
const StoreContext = createContext<RootStore | undefined>(undefined);

// create the provider component
function RootStoreProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  //only create the store once ( store is a singleton)
  const root = store ?? new RootStore()
  store = root
  return <StoreContext.Provider value={root}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
}

// create the hook
function useRootStore() {
  const context = useContext(StoreContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useRootStore must be used within RootStoreProvider")
  }

  return context
}
```

Just make sure you don't access other stores in the constructor functions, because of the initialization order some child store might not be created at that point.

I've written a post about this pattern a while ago:
[Mobx root store pattern with react hooks](https://dev.to/ivandotv/mobx-root-store-pattern-with-react-hooks-318d) you will also find a link to a demo project with Nextjs.

Comment: In the React part: Why have the store variable? You never set it.

Comment: @maracuja-juice fixed. We check if the store contains a value, if not, we create the RootStore. Next time the store will have a value , and we will skip the creation